# AmazonSQSException: Value aws:arn for parameter Condition must be from Global context key list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, aws-access-policy, assume-role

I am trying to set SQS access policy where everyone expect me in the organization can not access the SQS. Below is the policy I am trying to set

```
 "Statement": 
   {
        "Sid": "DenyEveryone",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "SQS:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:{accountnumber}:name-of-sqs",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:arn": "arn:aws:sts::{accountnumber}:assumed-role/{Developer_AWS_Role}/{my_employee_id}"
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try and do this, I get following error

```
Failed to save changes to the policy document. Reason: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: 
Value aws:arn for parameter Condition is invalid. 
Reason: Conditions must be from Global context key list 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html. 
(Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: {request_id})
```

Does anyone have an idea why am I not able to do this? Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the idea of your `Condition` block?

Comment: @dmigo Basically deny everyone unless its me trying to access this SQS via the console.

Comment: If I get you right that you want to only allow the usage of the `SQS` to one particular user, then it means that you need just a policy that allows usage and then assign it to one of your roles. Everyone else won't have access to it by default, unless they have a similar role/policy.